# Download a dynamic CSV file as an attachment via Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express

When a GET request is sent to a certain API endpoint, CSV string is dynamically created to be served as file attachment.

I have tried to do the following:

```
const agesMap = 'person1,23\nperson2,32\nperson3,21 ...';
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/csv');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=ages.csv');
res.write(agesMap);
res.end();
```

**Unfortunately file download wasn't triggered, but instead it was just a response to the original request.**

The Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Pragma:no-cache
```

The Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=ages.csv
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-type:text/csv
Pragma:no-cache
Surrogate-Control:no-store
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin, Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control:off
X-Download-Options:noopen
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you requesting through XHR?